# servlet: error trying to convert string to int. throws NumberFormatException: For input String: "2/"

Tags: servlets, numberformatexception

my code in servlet is:

int gid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("deleteid"));

where deleteid is hidden form field in jsp.
The glassfish server log states that,
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2/"

Comment: problem solved. Done following changes:
int gid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("deleteid").replaceAll("/",""));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its appending "/" after number I just used following method to solve the problem. Sorry for asking it at the first place:

int gid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("deleteid").replaceAll("/"));